# Как умножить числа двух столбцов и записать в третий sqlite3 python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Имеется таблица с двумя столбцами чисел и третий пустой. Как перемножить значения двух столбцов и записать в третий, так чтобы напротив каждых двух чисел в третьем столбце было их произведение, не используя GENERATED ALWAYS?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
def s_days():
sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('my.db')
cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
sqlite_connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor.execute("SELECT a FROM my_table")
q = cursor.fetchall()
for qq in q:
    df = "UPDATE my_table SET c = (a * b) WHERE a = (?);"
    cursor.execute(df, (qq))
    sqlite_connection.commit()
cursor.close()
sqlite_connection.close()
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1486758/edit)».